# Oracle query works in Query Designer but previewing report results in error

Tags: oracle, reporting-services, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-data-tools

I've been given an RDL file for a report we use at work and I am trying to get it running on my development PC. I started a new reporting services project in Visual Studio 2017 and added the report file to it. The report's dataset is embedded inside of it.

If I open the Dataset Properties and run Query Designer I can execute the query and I get the expected results back. However, when I try and preview the report, it gives me these errors:

`An error occurred during local report processing.
An error has occurred during report processing.
Query execution failed for dataset 'ds'.
ORA-00905: missing keywordORA-00905: missing keyword`

The query also works if I try it in SQL Developer or Tableau, so not sure why the report preview is not working (especially since it can run in the Query Designer). I'm not even sure how to go about troubleshooting this!

If it matters, the `.rdl` file was created using Visual Studio 2012 and I am using 2017.

Comment: Could you post that query? Maybe it'll help someone help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm still not sure what the root cause was here, but I wound up uninstalling my Oracle clients and the Oracle Developer Tools for VS and reinstalled everything following these instructions: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dataaccesstechnologies/2018/03/26/configure-oracle-data-source-for-sql-server-reporting-services-ssdt-and-report-server/

Everything is working now and I'm no longer getting any SQL syntax errors on my query. Hope this helps someone in the same boat!